# How can I make my Rest API method only accessible from my Application's sign-up page?

Tags: python, android, rest, flask

I am coding Rest API with python flask for my Android app (I don't know if it is a good decision to code Rest API with Python for the Android app). There is a post and get methods for users:

```
@app.route('/user/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def user_page():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        id_parameter = str(request.args.get('id'))
        user = getUserById(id_parameter)
        if not user: return json.dumps({'Error':'Invalid parameter(s)'})
        data_set = {'UserID':user.id,'Username':user.username,'Password':user.password}   
        json_dump = json.dumps(data_set)
        
        return json_dump
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username_parameter = str(request.args.get('username'))
        password_parameter = str(request.args.get('password'))
        print(username_parameter,password_parameter)
        insertUsers(username_parameter,password_parameter)
        return 'SUCCESS'
```

But for now, the user post method is accessible from anywhere, even online API testers. It is a big security error that everyone can add new users to the database from everywhere.

How can I make this Rest API accessible from only my Application's sign-up page?

Comment: You cannot do that reliable, any such check can be easily worked around. For common patterns search for CSP (Content security policy), but this will protect only for browsers and other entities that do not try to use your API *themselves* with malicious intent. CSP protection does not prevent me from `curl`-ing your API. The only way to prevent arbitrary people from using your API is authentication, but usually you cannot require authentication for registration (it's an endless loop).

Comment: So this means, it is not a big problem and this statement also same in the other applications like Instagram?

Comment: Anyone can mimic your requests and replay them. To prevent common security problems, it is essential to use standard authentication and authorization protocols. If security is a concern for you, I advise against reinventing your own authentication/authorization protocol, as they often have simple vulnerabilities. I recommend using JWT or OAuth, which have suitable plugins available for Flask or FastAPI. Additionally, I suggest using FastAPI for implementing Python REST services.

Answer (score 0):

--I think what you are trying to do can be solved by the `window.location.href` property of JavaScript. This property returns the location of the user. By pairing this with ajax, you can check whether the user's location is your signup page location. Then you can perform the necessary operation  ( NOT SURE)

--Another simple way is to redirect the user to a captcha prompt.

Comment: How would that prevent me sending the necessary location manually?

Comment: I am not sure whether API testers can send ajax requests to servers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).